# notifications with unique ids get overwritten

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

I am building an app where user can subscribe to get notification at a specific time. But when I try putting two notifications one after the other, things get horribly wrong.

My code:

```
    myObject.setNotificationId((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE)); // unique
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), 
    NotificationReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("object", objectToJson(myObject)); //GSON


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, myObject.getNotificationId(),
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(// the time user has chosen);


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // will trigger even if device goes to sleep mode
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 120000L, pendingIntent);
        Log.v(TAG, "Notification is setup.");
```

I have put the repeat for 2 minutes just to see if it works.

NotificationRecevier class - onReceive method

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
   (NotificationManager)
context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent moreDetailsIntent = new Intent(context, 
    MoreDetailsActiviy.class); //open this when clicked


moreDetailsIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));// dummy code

String strObj = intent.getStringExtra("object");
        MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(strObj, MyObject.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, myObject.getNotificationId(),
                moreDetailsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("SOME TEXT HERE")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(myObject.getNotificationId(), builder.build());
```

My testing:
Time is 13:10. Set notification to start at 13:14 and run every 2 minutes. (id 1). Set another notification to start 13:17 and run every 2 minutes. (id 2)

1. Time is 13:14 - First notification (with id 1) fires
2. Time is 13:16 - First notification should fire again but it doesnt
3. Time is 13:17 - Second notification (with id 2) fires
4. Time is 13:18 - First notification should fire again but it doesnt
5. Time is 13:19 - Second notification should fire again but it doesnt

After that nothing fires.

I tried changing FLAG_ONE_SHOT to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Time is 13:20. Set notification to start at 13:22 and run every 2 minutes. (id 1). Set another notification to start 13:33 and run every 2 minutes. (id 2)

1. Time is 13:22 - First notification (with id 1) fires
2. Time is 13:24 - First notification fires again
3. Time is 13:26 - First notification fires again
4. Time is 13:28 - First notification fires again
5. Time is 13:30 - First notification fires again
6. Time is 13:32 - First notification should fire again but it doesnt
7. Time is 13:33 - Both notifications fire at the same time
8. Time is 13:34 - First notification should fire again but it doesnt
9. Time is 13:35 - Both notifications fire at the same time

And it continues like this. Why is this happening?

Thanks. Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: In the docs : `Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact.` - this means that you can't have "exact" alarms - your second trial with updated flags is expected behaviour - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html it does state that you can use legacy behaviour : `Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.` I suggest setting your target sdk to 18 and test again.

Comment: I will try that. So basically the issue is that Android synchronizes both of these notifications (because they are close to each other with respect to time) and sends them simultaneously. Correct? So if I make the time between each notification greater it will still send them as they are supposed to?

Comment: I tried this and it worked. API 18 does send them in the exact time. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: As with job scheduler, later versions of android try to batch background work together to limit cpu wake ups for less battery impact, this does make sense, but can be more complicated to get desired behaviour (or as close a possible to desired behaviour) because of these restrictions.